# How to declare different structs inside one array in Swift

Tags: swift, struct

Is it possible to create an array of different structs?
My data structure looks like this:

```
enum MovementType: String, Codable {
    case WeightMovement
    case RepsMovement
}

struct Movement: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let name: String
    let type: MovementType
    let workouts: [WeightMovement, RepsMovement] ---> A solution for this line based on the Type above
}

struct WeightMovement: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let weight: Double
    let sets: Int
    let reps: Int
}

struct RepsMovement: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let sets: Int
    let reps: Int
    let seconds: Int
}
```

A brief example of what is should do:
A user can create multiple movements with a name and movementType. A user can add workouts to a movement but since each movementType holds different data i create different structs for that.

ideally the array will always hold only one type of Movement based on the `type` of the movement.

Comment: You can make your model structs confirm to base type, can be a empty class or a protocol based on your requirement. Create array of base type, and append objects using composition , instead of passing every type individually, which is itself wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to declare the properties whose presence is uncertain as optional and create a common `struct` that combines both of the optional properties. Since we already have a `MovementType` that would provide certainty about the availability of a particular property we could probably force-unwrap, although safe-unwrap is safer at any point.

```
struct Movement: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    let name: String
    let type: MovementType
    let workouts: [MovementDetail]
}

struct MovementDetail: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    let weight: Double?
    let sets: Int
    let reps: Int
    let seconds: Int?
}

enum MovementType: String, Codable {
    case WeightMovement
    case RepsMovement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```swift
struct Movement: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var type: MovementType
    var weightWorkouts: [WeightMovement]
    var repsWorkouts: [RepsMovement]
    var workouts: [Codable] {
        switch type {
        case .WeightMovement:
            return weightWorkouts
        case .RepsMovement:
            return repsWorkouts
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't do *exactly* what you describe, as there are multiple array types on the struct, but for the object's consumer, you have access to a single property `workouts` that will return one of multiple possible types.

As Tushar points out in his comment, though, it is fragile to specify what the return type is in two different places (`type` and the actual type returned in the array). A subclass or protocol would probably be better.

Answer (score 0):

> ideally the array will always hold only one type of Movement based on the type of the movement.

In this case I recommend to decode the JSON *manually* and declare the type enum with associated types

```
enum MovementType {
    case weight([WeightMovement])
    case reps([RepsMovement])
}

struct Movement: Identifiable, Decodable {
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case name, type, workouts }
    
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let name: String
    let type: MovementType
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        let movementType = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        switch movementType {
            case "WeightMovement":
                let workouts = try container.decode([WeightMovement].self, forKey: .workouts)
                type = .weight(workouts)
            case "RepsMovement":
                let workouts = try container.decode([RepsMovement].self, forKey: .workouts)
                type = .reps(workouts)
            default: throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .type, in: container, debugDescription: "Invalid movement type")
        }
    }
}

struct WeightMovement: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let weight: Double
    let sets: Int
    let reps: Int
}

struct RepsMovement: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let sets: Int
    let reps: Int
    let seconds: Int
}
```

The explicit UUID assignment implies that `id` is not going to be decoded.